# App Engine: How to persist related entities using Objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Given the following configuration

```
@Entity
public class A{
  …
  private List<Key<B>>bees;
  …
}

@Entity
public class B{
  …
}
```

How do I persist B such that it belongs to the collection of `bees` in A? Must I persist it twice? Back when I use using JPA/JDO with Datanucleus all I did was

```
A aa = getA();
B bb = createB(…);
aa.getBees().add(bb);
aa.update();
```

But with Objectify do I have to persist it twice? As in, must I do

```
A aa = getA();
B bb = createB(…);

aa.getBees().add(bb.getKey());
ofy().save().entity(bb).now();
ofy().save().entity(aa).now();
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what you are asking, but the #1 best practice when persisting related entities is to explicitly allocate ids using the allocator. In fact, you're best off never using the "null Long ids are set on save" feature.

Thus, to save an A and a B:

```
B b = new B(...);    // Id set by ObjectifyFactory.allocateId()
A a = new A(...);    // Id set by ObjectifyFactory.allocateId()
a.getBees().add(b.getKey());
ofy().save().entities(a, b);
```

Personally I would add the `b` to `A`'s constructor.

Comment: I am manually creating my keys as `pageKey=KeyFactory.createKey(bookKey, Page.class.getSimpleName(), bookId+""+pageNumber)` So practically I already have the keys. So I imagine that is the same as using `ObjectifyFactory.allocateId()`. I am literally using a `Key` as opposed to Long or String

Comment: Also the following line is not compiling `a.getBees().add(b.getKey());` I cannot add a datastore key to an objectify generic. Do you know how to fix this? tag @tx802

Comment: You can convert between native datastore `Key` and Objectify's `Key<?>` trivially enough. This is a Java 101 question easily answered by Objectify's Javadocs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to put both `aa` and `bb` (as per your example). Remember, there's nothing special about the list of `B`s in your `A` — it's just like any other multi-valued property, but those values are `Key`s instead of `Long`s or `String`s.

So, when you persist `aa`, Objectify doesn't then 'follow' those keys and persist the referenced entities.  I'll defer to *stickfigure* but I imagine this is by design as it could introduce some unexpected writes, which could affect your application's cost and performance.

Comment: I am manually creating my keys as `pageKey=KeyFactory.createKey(bookKey, Page.class.getSimpleName(), bookId+""+pageNumber)` So practically I already have the keys. So I imagine that is the same as using `ObjectifyFactory.allocateId()`. I am literally using a `Key` as opposed to Long or String

Comment: Also the following line is not compiling `a.getBees().add(b.getKey());` I cannot add a datastore key to an objectify generic. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know what `b.getKey()` is but you should be able to add `Key.create(b)` to your `List `